# Filter json object if keys exists in another object

Tags: json, bash, command-line, jq

I have two files

file1.json

```
{
  "a": "x1",
  "b": "y1",
  "c": "z1"
}
```

file2.json

```
{
  "a": "x2",
  "b": "y2"
}
```

Since a & b already exists in file2, I want to output a new object that contains only c. The values don't really matter.

```
{
  "c": "z1"
}
```

I tried

```
jq -s '.[0] | to_entries | map(select(.key | in(.[1]) | not)) | from_entries' temp1.json temp2.json
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
jq: error (at temp2.json:4): Cannot index string with number
```

The funny thing, when I try:

```
jq -s '.[0] | to_entries | map(select(.key | in({"a": "x2", "b": "y2"}) | not)) | from_entries' file1.json file2.json
```

I get the right output. So it just seems like jq is treating .[1] as an int? and not as a json object.

Comment: `.key |` makes your `.` be a string, like `"a"`. What do you expect `"a"[1]` to mean?

Answer (score 0):

This "hack" is what did it for me so far. I am curious if there is anything better.

```
jq -s '. as $input | $input[0] | to_entries | map(select(.key | in($input[1]) | not)) | from_entries' temp1.json temp2.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward approach using `reduce`:

```
jq -n --argfile one file1.json --argfile two file2.json '
 reduce ($two|keys_unsorted)[] as $k ($one; delpaths([[$k]]))'
```

And here is a more efficient filter that still uses `delpaths`:

```
$one | delpaths($two|keys_unsorted|map([.]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function for performing object subtraction:

```
# remove from $x all the keys that occur in $y
def minus($x; $y):
  ((($x + $y)|to_entries) - ($y|to_entries))
  | from_entries;
```

This can be used to solve the problem in a variety of ways, e.g. with the invocation:

```
jq -n -f program.jq file1.json file2.json
```

where program.jq contains the above def followed by:

```
minus(input; input)
```